# Cyan,Magenta,and Yellow are displayed using 2 subpixels.Red,Green,and Blue only light one for each.How come C,M,Y don't look much brighter than R,G,B?

Tags: display, colors, lcd, pixels, rgb

LCD screens have pixels that consist of 3 sub-pixels: red, green, and blue. The colors red, green, and blue are made with only one color.

[image]

The colors yellow (red + green), magenta (red + blue), and cyan (green + blue) are made by mixing 2 colors.

[image]

What I don't get is: If yellow, magenta, and cyan use twice the amount of light output from the pixels than red, green, and blue, then why don't we perceive Y,M,C to be much brighter than R,G,B?

[image]

The above image is R,G,B.

[image]

The above image is Y,M,C.

Why do they appear to be about the same brightness?

If I make Y,M,C each have 50% of the brightness output from the sub-pixels, I get the following, which is way darker than R,G,B.

[image]

However, I know that human vision perceives brightness non-linearly. 188/255 is 50% gray on a linear brightness scale, and 50% + 50% = 100%.

[image]

However, these colors still appear much darker than R,G,B.

**What am I missing about how LCD colors are displayed? I don't get this.**

Comment: I suspect that this would be better asked on a site that deal with vision in general; this is not really a question about computer hardware or software.

Comment: The title of your question should reflect the content of the question. Attached is a guide to this end (How to ask a good question) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Yeah, this is a human perception problem, possibly the Helmholtz–Kohlrausch effect ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz%E2%80%93Kohlrausch_effect ). Basically, luminance and brightness are not perceived the same across all wavelengths and can be heavily influenced by context.

Comment: Also: green is relatively bright (it carries the most of the luminance) and red and blue are darker. Just compare them all at level 255, it is clearly visible. Therefore G+R and G+B are quite bright, but the second color does not add too much there. Compared to them, R+B is relatively dark (when you compare all of them at level 255). This also partially adds to the answer. It won't be "much brighta" because R and B are not perceived as very bright even at the maximum level.

Comment: You've received comments on your question warning you that it might not be on the best site and you offer a bounty for it without answering the comments.  WHY???

Comment: don't delete the question by removing content like that

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare brightness of RGB to CMY(K). RGB is intended to represent colors on displays (that emit light), CMYK is intended to represent colors when printed on white substrate (like paper, that reflect light). Also CMYK is only a subset of RGB colorspace.

Saying all that, your error is that you think of colors separately, while in fact the three subpixels can not be viewed separately. RGB (255, 255, 0) translates to CMY (0, 0, 100%). So, three subpixels of a single color dot in RGB space got translated to their corresponding 3 colors in CMY space. But still, it is a single dot. You can think about it like rotation of coordinates.

You can also think about HSV color space. Hue - is the relative mix of RGB colors, Saturation - how much intensity this mix has, and Value - how bright you pixel is.

You can read more on that [here](http://dba.med.sc.edu/price/irf/Adobe_tg/models/rgbcmy.html)

(50%, 50%, 50%) CMY translates exactly to (128,128,128) RGB.
If your **printed** image does not look like the one on display, then your display/printer are not properly calibrated.

Comment: as far as i understand, the question isn't about CMYK vs. RGB, but about why one pixel with RGB 255/255/0 isn't brighter than the same pixel with RGB 255/0/0. that being said, it still might have more to do with perception than with display design.

Comment: If you consider how LCD is built, you will understand that (255,255,0) is brighter than (255, 0, 0). Each sub pixel has a color film filter, and liquid crystal part is controlling the amount of (back)light passed through. It has nothing to do with perception.